# How to prove that $\binom{X+L-1}{L-1} \ge (X-L\times N)^{L-1}$?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, proof-verification, binomial-coefficients

I would like to prove the following expression:
$$\binom{X+L-1}{L-1} \ge (X-L\times N)^{L-1}$$
, where $X$, $L$ and $N$ are positive integers. Please help me to prove with the following case.

$X\ge L\times N$

Comment: Take $X = 0$ to get a counterexample when $L$ is odd

Comment: @cats: OP saids that $X >0$

Comment: If $L$ is odd and $L\ne 1$ the RHS can be arbitrarily large by taking $ N$ large enough, without changing the LHS. Is something missing in the Q?

Comment: @cats: I have modified the question.

Comment: @user254665: I have modified the question

Comment: Hint: the binomial coefficient is the product of $L-1$ terms. What is the smallest  of these terms? What lower bound does that lead to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $N=1,L=3$ we have $L N=3.$ But $\binom {X+2}{2}= (X+2)(X+1)/2 < (X-3)^2 $  for $X\geq 21.$ So the proposition is false.

Comment: When $X$ increases to sufficient large, the proposition is false. Would you mind proving when $X$ is small enough?

Comment: You might try treating $N$ as the free variable and take the $(L-1)$th root of both sides and use  Stirling's $n!=(1+d_n)(n/e)^n  \sqrt  {2 \pi n}$  where $|d_n|<1/6 n$ for $n>0.$ This might give some info  about $N$ for sufficiently large values of $X$ and $L.$